# Popup Form bug on Onclick

Tags: javascript, html

i have these botton that when click should the Popup form show. but what happening is it's poping up for a second then gone when click what im doing wrong? I think my code is alright.

button code:

```
<button onclick="Openform()">Add New WorkStation</button>
```

javascript:

```
 <script>
        function Openform() {
            document.getElementById('popupform').style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

css:

```
.divpopup {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-top: auto;
                display: none;
            }
```

the  div that should popup:

```
 <div id="popupform" class="divpopup">

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWorkStation" runat="server" placeholder="WorkStation Name"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWorkStation" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="InActive" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have an extra `</div>`. Try removing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using a button, and that causes a postback that resets the page.

You can add a return value that basically cancels the original postback of the button:

```
<button onclick="Openform(); return false;">Add New WorkStation</button>
```

Or use an input of type button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="Openform()" value="Add New WorkStation" />
```

Or another way of canceling the button's natural postback behavior:

```
function Openform() {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('popupform').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: solve by calling the javascript funtion in server side c#. by the thank you